# Unable to get Model object from db.session.execute in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

From the [official docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/queries/), I should be able to do:

```
user = db.session.execute(db.select(User).filter_by(username=username)).one()
```

To get the user object. Here is my `User` model:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = Column(Text, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    
    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)
```

My helper function:

```
def get_user(user_email):
    return db.session.execute(db.select(models.User).filter_by(email=user_email)).one()
```

Why does this happen when I query:

```
def check_user_password(email, password):
    user = utils.get_user(email)
    if not user.verify_password(password):
        print("not valid password")

    print("All good")
```

> AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'verify_password'

I was under the impression that I would get my `User` model object back, so that I could call `user.verify_password()` function. Instead what looks to be happening is it's trying to find a column instead.

I also tried `.first()` instead of `.one()`, as well as `.all()[0]`, but they all get me the same result.

How do I get my `User` object here? Similarly, if I wanted multiple User objects using `.all()`, what would be the appropriate query statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked docs tell you that `db.session.execute` will return a `Result` object. To get the `User` instance you need to extract the first element from the result:

```py
db.session.execute(db.select(models.User).filter_by(email=user_email)).one()[0]
```

or more conveniently, use `session.scalars` which will return model instances without the `Result` wrapper:

```py
db.session.scalars(db.select(models.User).filter_by(email=user_email)).one()
```

Comment: What's the difference between doing `db.session.scalars().one()` and `db.execute().scalars().one()`? Is one more efficient than the other?

Comment: No real difference - `session.scalars9)` calls `session.execute().scalars()` as you can see [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/b924ba949cb8aa1bd73f7438600caf92a3b732b3/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L1752).